# how to call a arrow function inside another function from outside?

Tags: javascript

```
function x(name){
    this.name = name;

    const arrow =() =>{
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Arrow" + this.name)
        },100)
    }

    const func1 = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Normal" + this.name)
        },100) 
    }

    arrow(name);
    func1(name);
}

x("BOB")
```

how to call func1 from outside after calling x("BOB") function
and how arrow functions change the value of this compared to normal functions

Comment: Is `x` supposed to be a constructor? Then you need to call `new x("BOB")`

Comment: x is a function ,  func1 is a function inside x in the code given i am calling func1 inside x , but i want to call func1 function outside x , after the line x("BOB")

Comment: Here is a demo https://jsfiddle.net/x6bku230/ Docs for reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Comment: @kichu But `func1` doesn't exist any longer after the line `x("BOB")`. So what do you want to change? Why do you want to call it outside? Do you want to be able to call it multiple times? Do you try to use OOP?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call arrow outside, you can try to return the function and call like this (closure concept)

```
    function x(name){
    this.name = name;

    const arrow =() =>{
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Arrow" + this.name)
        },100)
    }

    const func1 = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Normal" + this.name)
        },100) 
    }

    arrow(name);
    func1(name);
    
    return arrow
}
arrow = x("BOB")
arrow()
```

But I prefer, you to try OOPs structure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the following example is exactly what you want:

```js
function x(name) {
  this.name = name;

  const arrow = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Arrow" + this.name);
    }, 100);
  };

  const func1 = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Normal" + this.name);
    }, 100);
  };

  arrow(name);
  func1(name);

  x.func1 = func1;
  x.arrow = arrow;
}

x("nawaf");
x.func1();
x.arrow();
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-water-y8oux

Comment: No. This is a horrible antipattern. Do not modify the function object from within the call.